# Codeigniter - image upload - open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, media, open-basedir

I have a simple cms which is written in Codeigniter framework. 
It has worked just fine in many projects and it still works ok on my local machine.
But when i put my recent web site online (server php version 5.5.17) and i try to upload an image, i get this error:

> Message: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is
>   not within the allowed path(s):
>   (.:/var/www/vhosts/web-test-host.tk:/tmp:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/lib/php/session)
>   Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php

I have tried everything, permissions are all set up, i have even set the open_basedir value to none and it still doesn't want to upload an image, neither doesn't get a name of the image.

Server php version is 5.5.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to write a file to /. Since this is outside the allowed paths for your website / vhost you cant write to it. Check your script, path configurations, you must be missing something in the destination.